# DependencyProperty / INotifyPropertyChanged on low level objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have some fairly low level classes that are used in a WPF application that I'm working on. One, for example represents an object that will be displayed as a list in a ScrollViewer and displayed with a DataTemplate.  The binding works great for the several properties that are used in the UI and I used this object purely because it was just convenient to pass up to the UI.  The problem is that the UI does not get notified of data changes because it does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged or DependencyProperty.

The classes mentioned are intended to be part of a library that could be used totally independent of the UI, so I'm worried about cluttering it up with UI specific stuff (especially with INPC, that thing is a crazy amount of code for such a little thing).

What would generally be done in this case, clutter up the low level classes with UI cruft or make a wrapper class that is for the UI.  Or is there another option?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably write a wrapper, though I don't know whether that would be the best option or not.

Answer (score 1):

For good separation I would create a class that wraps your library class. The wrapper would implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and expose public properties that fire the PropertyChanged event when updated. The wrapper would get and set the actual values from the wrapped class...

```
public class Internal
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class WrapperForInternal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);

    private Internal _i;
    public WrapperForInternal(Internal i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _i.MyProperty; }
        set
        {
            _i.MyProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could derive from the Internal class and add the interface and an extra property that fires the event. But I would prefer the complete separation myself.

Comment: Well, one part of the problem there is that the values might be changed in the underlying classes due to worker threads running in some of the lower code... so I guess the PropertyChanged events wouldn't get fired in that case?

Comment: In that case I would recommend you make the Internal property MyProperty virtual and then inherit a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. Also override the MyProperty so it fires the change event when it is updated.